# Recursion through a directory tree in PHP

Tags: php, recursion, directory

I have a set of folders that has a depth of at least 4 or 5 levels. I'm looking to recurse through the directory tree as deep as it goes, and iterate over every file. I've gotten the code to go down into the first sets of subdirectories, but no deeper, and I'm not sure why. Any ideas?

```
$count = 0;
$dir = "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/site.com";
function recurseDirs($main, $count){
    $dir = "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/site.com";
    $dirHandle = opendir($main);
    echo "here";
    while($file = readdir($dirHandle)){
        if(is_dir($file) && $file != '.' && $file != '..'){
            echo "isdir";
            recurseDirs($file);
        }
        else{
            $count++;
            echo "$count: filename: $file in $dir/$main \n<br />";
        }
    }
}
recurseDirs($dir, $count);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call to is_dir and recurseDirs is not fully correct. Also your counting didn't work correctly. This works for me:

```
$dir = "/usr/";
function recurseDirs($main, $count=0){
    $dirHandle = opendir($main);
    while($file = readdir($dirHandle)){
        if(is_dir($main.$file."/") && $file != '.' && $file != '..'){
            echo "Directory {$file}: <br />";
            $count = recurseDirs($main.$file."/",$count); // Correct call and fixed counting
        }
        else{
            $count++;
            echo "$count: filename: $file in $main \n<br />";
        }
    }
    return $count;
}
$number_of_files = recurseDirs($dir);
```

Notice the changed calls to the function above and the new return value of the function.

Answer (score 17):

Check out the new [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php).

It's still far from perfect as you can't order the search results and other things, but to simply get a list of files, it's fine.

There are simple examples to get you started in the manual like this one:

```
<?php

$path = realpath('/etc');

$objects = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path), 
RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

foreach($objects as $name => $object){
    echo "$name\n";
}

?>
```

Comment: Just one remark: an iterator does what it's name implies. It iterates over an iterable source. That's no different from iterating over an array. If you'd want the results sorted, then you'd have to do this in the foreach loop or write/use a function to do this for you.

Comment: @Gordon true. But being able to get the results sorted and/or filtered straight away is a feature I would expect from a recursive directory iterator nevertheless - I understand that that may not be in the spririt of the SPL, but still. As it is, there is again the need to come up with dozens of lines of code (with hundreds of snippets on the net, all varying in quality) to perform a pretty standard task, where other languages offer ready-made functions. That pisses me off a bit sometimes.

Comment: @Pekka Since everything can be an Iterable now, it is impossible to come up with a generic sort. How should it know I want my Person objects to be sorted by $firstName but my Files by MTime? You *have* to script that. If you want to query objects by generic expressions, have a look at PHPLinq.

Comment: @Gordon true, and not the job of an iterator. I guess what I'm trying to say is, I would like to see a PHP standard library for file operations that is better and more powerful than what is available right now.

Comment: @Pekka have a look at http://github.com/theseer/DirectoryScanner or http://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-file-iterator then. Also, I am currently in the process of writing a FilterIterator that allows for filtering based on File attributes.

Comment: @Gordon thanks for the links, they look exactly like what I'm looking for! We really, really need a central repository for high-quality PHP code.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345412/quality-php-code-snippet-repositories

Answer (score 2):

There is an error in the call

```
recurseDirs($file);
```

and in

```
is_dir($file)
```

you have to give the full path:

```
recurseDirs($main . '/' .$file, $count);
```

and

```
is_dir($main . '/' .$file)
```

However, like other anwerers, I suggest to use [`RecursiveDirectoryIteretor`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php).

Answer (score 0):

So yeah: Today I was being lazy and Googled for a cookie cutter solution to a recursive directory listing and came across this. As I ended up writing my own function (as to why I even spent the time to Google for this is beyond me - I always seem to feel the need to re-invent the wheel for no suitable reason) I felt inclined to share my take on this.

While there are opinions for and against the use of RecursiveDirectoryIterator, I'll simply post my take on a simple recursive directory function and avoid the politics of chiming in on RecursiveDirectoryIterator.

Here it is:

```
function recursiveDirectoryList( $root )
{

    /* 
     * this next conditional isn't required for the code to function, but I
     * did not want double directory separators in the resulting array values 
     * if a trailing directory separator was provided in the root path;
     * this seemed an efficient manner to remedy said problem easily...
     */
    if( substr( $root, -1 ) === DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR )
    {
        $root = substr( $root, 0, strlen( $root ) - 1 );
    }

    if( ! is_dir( $root ) ) return array();

    $files = array();
    $dir_handle = opendir( $root );

    while( ( $entry = readdir( $dir_handle ) ) !== false )
    {

        if( $entry === '.' || $entry === '..' ) continue;

        if( is_dir( $root . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $entry ) )
        {
            $sub_files = recursiveDirectoryList( 
                $root . 
                DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 
                $entry . 
                DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR 
            );
            $files = array_merge( $files, $sub_files );
        }
        else
        {
            $files[] = $root . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $entry;
        }
    }

    return (array) $files;

}
```

With this function, the answer as to obtaining a file count is simple:

```
$dirpath = '/your/directory/path/goes/here/';

$files = recursiveDirectoryList( $dirpath );

$number_of_files = sizeof( $files );
```

But, if you don't want the overhead of an array of the respective file paths - or simply don't need it - there is no need to pass a count to the recursive function as was recommended.

One could simple amend my original function to perform the counting as such:

```
function recursiveDirectoryListC( $root )
{

    $count = 0;

    if( ! is_dir( $root ) ) return (int) $count;

    $dir_handle = opendir( $root );

    while( ( $entry = readdir( $dir_handle ) ) !== false )
    {

        if( $entry === '.' || $entry === '..' ) continue;

        if( is_dir( $root . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $entry ) )
        {
            $count += recursiveDirectoryListC(
                $root .
                DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .
                $entry .
                DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
            );
        }
        else
        {
            $count++;
        }

    }

    return (int) $count;

}
```

In both of these functions the opendir() function should really be wrapped in a conditional in the event that the directory is not readable or another error occurs. Make sure to do so correctly:

```
if( ( $dir_handle = opendir( $dir ) ) !== false ) 
{ 
    /* perform directory read logic */ 
}
else
{
    /* do something on failure */
}
```

Hope this helps someone...